# Optimizing Interactive SVG JavaScript Animation

Tags: javascript, css, svg, optimization, svg-animate

I am trying to animate SVG's in a web browser using JavaScript. My current methodology is using innerHTML:

```js
var e = new entity();

function draw() {
  element = document.getElementById("canvas");
  e.radius += .1;
  e.pos[0] += .1; e.pos[1] += .1;
  var insides = "";
  insides += '<svg height="80%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">' + e.show() + '</svg>';
  element.innerHTML = insides;
}

function entity() {
  this.pos = [0, 0];
  this.radius = 1;
  this.show = function() {
    return '<circle cx="' + String(this.pos[0]) + '" cy="' + String(this.pos[1]) + '" r="' + String(this.radius) + '" />';
  }
}
window.setInterval(draw, 60);
```

```html
<div id="canvas" style="text-align:center;"></div>
```

I want to make sure I am not wasting too many resources, so are there any ways that are less resource-intensive in the HTML document/JavaScript to do controlled interactive animations with SVG's such as this?

Comment: SMIL would be even more efficient.

Comment: I am trying to avoid SMIL, as it has limited compatability.

Comment: It has great compatibility since it runs on all browsers if you use the fakeSmile polyfill https://leunen.me/fakesmile/

Comment: Okay, I'll look into fakeSmile, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recreating the whole SVG every time is extremely inefficient.  Just update the geometry attributes.

```js
var e = new entity();

function draw() {
  element = document.getElementById("canvas");
  e.radius += .1;
  e.pos[0] += .1; e.pos[1] += .1;
  e.show();
}

function entity() {
  this.element = document.getElementById("mycircle");
  this.pos = [0, 0];
  this.radius = 1;
  this.show = function() {
    this.element.cx.baseVal.value = this.pos[0];
    this.element.cy.baseVal.value = this.pos[1];
    this.element.r.baseVal.value = this.radius;
  }
}

window.setInterval(draw, 60);
```

```html
<div id="canvas" style="text-align:center;">
  <svg height="80%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle id="mycircle" cx="0" cy="0" r="0" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you think would be the best way to add shapes to the canvas after the DOM is loaded?

Comment: Use `document.createElementNS()`. Check out other questions here for how to do this. There are plenty of examples on SO. It is a frequently asked question.

Comment: Also, would editing the value of the position of multiple entities trigger a re-draw after each edit, or only re-draw after the script was done running?

Comment: It would typically happen when the browser is next idle.  Incrementing the coords in a javascript loop would not work as an animation.  You need to do it on each timeout, interval, or animationFrame.